# VLC ActiveX - branding property

Tags: winforms, vlc

I cannot find the property "branding" mentioned here:
https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/

Is it available for axvlc object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regrettably, this option is available for the NPAPI plugin only. It was not implemented for the ActiveX control as of yet.

This would be quite simple to implement. A patch would be welcome, but we could also provide guidance.